# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "events" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm working on an existing app and I'm in the process of getting it setup on my local environment however I'm running into a few issues:

**1.** I've pulled down the latest code, and dumped the DB from the in-house developer. It was a .sql file, so I used the following command:

```
$psql -h localhost -U root -d thms_development < /Users/me/mypath/public.sql
```

**2.** This seemed to have work, but throughout the dump process I'd see
    the odd error like:

```
ERROR:  role "rails_staging" does not exist

NOTICE:  table "bidding_plans" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
ERROR:  type "public.eh_allocation_plan_status" does not exist
LINE 6:  "status" "public"."eh_allocation_plan_status" DEFAULT 'clos...
                  ^
ERROR:  relation "public.bidding_plans" does not exist
BEGIN
ERROR:  relation "public.bidding_plans" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "public"."bidding_plans" VALUES ('8204668e-ca65-...
```

And other similar ones.

**3.** And finally when I boot the app up, and click on the events link, I
    get the following:

```
Started GET "/api/v2/client_events/events_for_venue?venue_id=7d72f8d9-f39f-4ed6-a24e-fb1cf23bd62e" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-18 19:49:40 -0400
Processing by Api::V2::ClientEventsController#events_for_venue as JSON
  Parameters: {"venue_id"=>"7d72f8d9-f39f-4ed6-a24e-fb1cf23bd62e"}
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "events" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"events"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"events"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms

PG::UndefinedTable - ERROR:  relation "events" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"events"'::regclass
                                          ^
:
```

I've ran db:setup, and this is the EXACT same code and DB that the current developer is using, what is going wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Along with the dump file, you want to know the command that produced it. The first error is to be expected, since roles are shared among dbs and they don't get dumped into a single db dump. But the second one looks problematic enough to make that file unusable as a stand-alone dump.

Answer (score 1):

The first error you received suggests that the SQL file contains code to run certain things as the `rails_staging` user. Your resolution to this will be to get the right SQL file or configuring your machine/DB precisely as the co-worker that generated that SQL file.

Comment: Thanks @smathy, I've gone back and forth with the dev and he has sent me his EXACT DB, and I have his exact codebase on my machine. How might I configure my machine to get this to work? First time I've ever experienced this issue. Cheers

Comment: Without looking at the file in depth (which this is not a good forum for me to do) this is a bit of a hacky recommendation, but try just adding the `rails_staging` role as an alias for `root`: `CREATE USER rails_staging IN ROLE root;` then try re-running your SQL import.

Comment: Ok giving this a shot!

Comment: So it looks like I'm getting less errors, but now when I run rake db:reset I get this one: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist, so to counter this I ran:       CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"; but i'm still getting the same error.., any idea how to get this working?

Comment: That sounds like it's because some requirements of the DB (here a sequence generator function) haven't been exported in that SQL file. Sorry, not sure what else I can do. You just have to comb through that file.